# Convert Android Widget to an App with a Widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

I have an Android widget (it is shown in the list of widgets on the phone, and is not shown in the list of apps). It has a button which launches a pop-up activity.
Now I would like to change the widget so, that it would be both an app (which will be shown in the list of apps on the phone) which will start from that pop-up activity, and a widget (the same as before) which will launch the app (which will consist of that pop-up activity, but will be displayed and treated like an app).
What changes should I make in my manifest file to make the changes described above?
Below is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <receiver android:name="myapp.myapp.MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="myapp.myapp.MyWidgetIntentReceiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GET_HELP" />
            <action android:name="CHANGE_PICTURE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="myapp.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="myapp.myapp.CardsChoice"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choice" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple: I just needed to add a Launcher Activity to the app.
This operation consists of 2 steps:

1. Adding activity definition as a launcher activity to the `Manifest`
   Example:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="package.package"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
       android:screenOrientation="portrait">

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>

   </activity>
   ```
2. Adding code of the activity (and the layout) to the app.
   It is about an class `MainActivity` and a layout file `activity_main.xml`